# how to explode a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I exploded a nested schema but I am not getting what I want,

before exploded it looks like this:

df.show()

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|CaseNumber|                   SourceId                               |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+
|       0  |[{"id":"1","type":"Sku"},{"id":"22","type":"ContractID"}] |
+----------|----------------------------------------------------------|
|       1  |[{"id":"3","type":"Sku"},{"id":"24","type":"ContractID"}] |                                             
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want it to be like this

```
+----------+-------------------+
| CaseNumber| Sku | ContractId |
+----------+-------------------+
|       0  | 1    |      22    |
+----------|------|------------|   
|       1  | 3    |      24    | 
+------------------------------|
```

Comment: please provide sample data for faster help/response

Comment: the above is the result set if you see the columns after "EventDateTime", they have the same values which is the case number but I want the values to be like the first picture

Comment: I have updated the question, Please see the above sample. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using the build-in `get_json_object` function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.get_json_object

val df = Seq(
  (0, """[{"id":"1","type":"Sku"},{"id":"22","type":"ContractID"}]"""),
  (1, """[{"id":"3","type":"Sku"},{"id":"24","type":"ContractID"}]"""))
.toDF("CaseNumber", "SourceId")

df.withColumn("sku", get_json_object($"SourceId", "$[0].id").cast("int"))
  .withColumn("ContractId", get_json_object($"SourceId", "$[1].id").cast("int"))
  .drop("SourceId")
  .show

// +----------+---+----------+
// |CaseNumber|sku|ContractId|
// +----------+---+----------+
// |         0|  1|        22|
// |         1|  3|        24|
// +----------+---+----------+
```

**UPDATE**

After our discussion we realised that the mentioned data is of `array<struct<id:string,type:string>>` type and not a simple string. Next is the solution for the new schema:

```
df.withColumn("sku", $"SourceIds".getItem(0).getField("id"))
  .withColumn("ContractId", $"SourceIds".getItem(1).getField("id"))
```

Comment: Thank you, the code works as I need it!! though the values come as strings both for "id" and "type" even though they are numbers, Can we modify the above code for string type? thanks

Comment: you need to the `id` as int you mean? if so is just a matter of a `cast` in the end. I modified the answer

Comment: I am getting this error "cannot resolve 'get_json_object(`sourceIds`, '$.id')' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires string type" 

the data comes as string so I like it to as string after exploding. thanks

Comment: your last code looks different Yonas :) `get_json_object(sourceIds, '$.id')` is invalid please check again the provided answer. I tested the mentioned change and it works

Comment: Yes, the values comes as strings for both, I don't want to change them to integers, when I tried the first code and the updated code with cast, it gave me the same error I posted earlier.

This is the schema

sourceIds: array
  |        element:struct
        |          id:string
            |      type:string
thanks

Comment: I dont understand what are you trying to achieve Yonas, you need the results as string or int? Please provide an example.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I need the results as string.

df.withColumn("sku", get_json_object($"SourceId", "$[0].id"))
  .withColumn("ContractId", get_json_object($"SourceId", "$[1].id"))
  .drop("SourceId")
  .show

With this code it has to work but when I execute, it raises that above error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205561/discussion-between-yonas-haile-and-alexandros-biratsis).